# This is showing 1-24 hours i need to 1-12 hours show how i can do this?

Tags: javascript

This is showing  1-24 hours i need to  1-12 hours show how i can do this ?

```
  function onbodyLoad (){
        var now = new Date();
        var hr = now.getHours();
        var min = now.getMinutes();
        var sec = now.getSeconds();
        document.getElementById('clockDisplay').innerHTML
            = "Time is " + hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
        setTimeout('onbodyLoad()', 500);

    }
```

Comment: Please don't spam your question onto meta etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getHours()` actually returns 0-23…here is how to convert that into 1-12:

```
var hr = time.getHours();

if (hr > 12) {
    hr -= 12;
} else if (hr=== 0) {
   hr = 12;
}
```